# how to get body from the response entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

This is my

```
ResponseEntity<String> response= new ResponseEntity<String> (
"\"<200 OK OK,{\\\"status\\\":200,\\\"success\\\":true,\\\"info\\\":{\\\"mid\\\":{\\\"id\\\":\\\"95706\\\"}}},[]>\"", HttpStatus.OK);
```

how to extract json from this response?

tried `response.getBody()` but giving me entire string.

Any help would be appreciated

```
response.getBody() but giving me entire string.
ResponseEntity<String> response= new ResponseEntity<String> (
"\"<200 OK OK,{\\\"status\\\":200,\\\"success\\\":true,\\\"info\\\":{\\\"mid\\\":{\\\"id\\\":\\\"95706\\\"}}},[]>\"", HttpStatus.OK);
```

response.getBody(); giving entire string not the json

Comment: Do you really need <200 OK OK, in the beginning of the string? You are already passing it to the ResponseEntity in the second parm as 200 OK.

Comment: That `String` is the body, so why should it return something else.

Comment: any json encode will help you to convert it to json object

Comment: Did you solve it? @vikas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve using:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response= new ResponseEntity<String> ("\"<200 OK OK,{\\\"status\\\":200,\\\"success\\\":true,\\\"info\\\":{\\\"mid\\\":\\\"id\\\":\\\"95706\\\"}}},[]>\"", HttpStatus.OK);


String responseStr = response.getBody();
int begin = responseStr.indexOf("{");
int end = responseStr.lastIndexOf("}") + 1;

responseStr = responseStr.substring(begin, end);
System.out.println(responseStr);
```

It will print:

```
{\"status\":200,\"success\":true,\"info\":{\"mid\":{\"id\":\"95706\"}}}
```